# My rest controller is not get called from URL

Tags: spring-boot, rest

My *Rest Controller* is not getting called. Can you kindly guide me?

I have created an API for bus reservation scenario for that my controller is not getting called.

Is there any issue in configuration?

I have tried by using following URL:

http://localhost:9090/service/api/bus/[enter link description here](http://localhost:9090/service/api/bus/)

debug breakpoint is also not coming.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/service")
public class ServiceController {

    @Autowired
    private ComponentDetailsService busService;

    @ApiOperation("This is the hello world api")
    @GetMapping("/api/bus/")
    public String hello() {
        ComponentDetailsEntity bus = new ComponentDetailsEntity();
        bus.setArrivalTime("10");
        bus.setBusNumber("TN11");
        bus.setDepature("salem");
        bus.setDestinationCity("chennai");
        bus.setDuration("5");
        bus.setOperatorName("bala");
        bus.setPrice(350);
        bus.setReturnDate(Date.valueOf("2020-5-4"));
        bus.setSourceCity("Salem");
        bus.setTravelDate(Date.valueOf("2020-5-3"));
        busService.postBus(bus);
        System.out.println("a");
        return "hello";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/api/bus/{sourceCity}/{destinationCity}/{travelDate}")
    public List<ComponentDetailsEntity> findAll(@PathVariable("sourceCity") String sourceCity, @PathVariable("destinationCity") String destinationCity,
            @PathVariable("travelDate") String strdate) {
        Date date = Date.valueOf(strdate);
        return  busService.findAll(sourceCity,destinationCity,date);
    }
}

server.port=9090
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=h2
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.h2.console.enabled=true

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>org.codejudge</groupId>
        <artifactId>sb</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>sb</name>
        <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <swagger.version>2.4.0</swagger.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <optional>true</optional>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                <version>${swagger.version}</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            

    </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springf

ramework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <finalName>spring-boot-in-docker</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <!-- This is needed if deploying with embedded server -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

Comment: Provide more details of exact issue you are facing. Your configuration seems good. GET call to http://localhost:9090/service/api/bus should return string "hello". Are you not able to see this string as well?

Comment: @SridharPatnaik yes i am not able to see hello instead i am seeing white label error.

Comment: What is the error. Are you  receiving 401, 403 or 500 400?

Comment: @SridharPatnaik   type=Not Found, status=404

Comment: Sorry I have to ask, but did you start your application? There is no problem with the given properties and class.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your console output, e.g. if there is any exception in your service class. The code you provided does work and generates the output "hello".